# how to remove \n when serializing a base64 String in android?

Tags: android

I am using Gson lib of google to serializing a base64 image String in JSON but in output due to new line \n comes which cause error while getting image from base64 string.

Comment: try finding some regular expression for it

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove spacing

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
  String jsonString = gson1.toJson(jsonMainNode);
```